# Concatenated GridLayout object has no attribute title using Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am putting together a GUI with Kivy for a Python (3.5) program. I am concatenating `GridLayout` objects to build grids inside grids. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
class SettingsPanel(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        GridLayout.__init__(self, cols=2);
        self.add_widget(Label(text='SubSubFoo'))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='SubSubFoo2')) 

class Panel(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        GridLayout.__init__(self, cols=1);
        self.add_widget(Label(text='SubFoo'))
        self.my_second_layer_grid = SubSubGrid()
        self.add_widget(self.my_second_layer_grid) 

class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "My app"
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text='Foo'))   
        self.my_panel = SubGrid()     
        layout.add_widget(self.my_panel)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':            
    GUI().run()
```

Although I successfully managed to work with what I call here `SubGrid`, in the moment I insert a `SubSubGrid` within the previous one, I get this error associated to the call `self.my_second_layer_grid = SubSubGrid()`

```
...
BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\style.kv", line 871:
...
    869:    Label:
    870:        size_hint_y: None
>>  871:        text: root.title
    872:        text_size: self.width - 32, None
    873:        height: max(50, self.texture_size[1] + 20)
...
AttributeError: 'SettingsPanel' object has no attribute 'title'
```

What is the problem?

Is Kivy having issues parsing the `Label`s code? If so, why doesn't it get the `text` field I provide? And why is it not a problem with the first `SubGrid`?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the comments below I realised my minimalistic version of the code was not only incorrect, but missed the actual core of the problem, which was about naming of the classes. I am updating the question before providing my own answer.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: The only error I see is a missing `return layout` in your `build()` method. After adding that, your code works fine for me with no error. The Exception you show looks like part of `style.kv` for the `<SettingsPanel>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with concatenation, but with naming.

The class `SettingsPanel` is already [defined in Kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.settings.html?highlight=settingspanel#kivy.uix.settings.SettingsPanel), and redefining it shadows the original, causing not surprisingly all sorts of issues to the parser.

My solution has been to simply call my class `SettingsSubPanel` instead.